# Enterprise Architect view not showing dependencies

Tags: oracle, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to create a view in Enterprise Architect called prodtakeoff for my Oracle schema.

I'm following:

http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.0/database_engineering/create_view.html

In creating the definition I created a dependency from my view to the source table.

When I open the view properties again it should show the table in the dependencies box but the dependencies box is empty.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You might have to report this as an issue (write to support@sparxsystems.com), 
But Hope you've seen that the Table higlighting and intellisense, which helps us to create the view definition, still works ok.